Java 8 JavaFX - How to set the color of the title text of a single tab
I have my UI layed out in an .fxml file, then I have a .css I use for defining the styles and a JavaFX Controller that extends AnchorPane.
In general it is not hard to style something, but the titles of Tabs are not explicitly defined in the .fxml and I seem to be unable to style it. I want to set the color of a single Tab to red.
Here are the approaches I have tried:
1- Setting the style directly in the .fxml:
    <Tab fx:id="tabRed" text="Tab 2" style="-fx-text-fill: red;">
        <content>
            <AnchorPane minHeight="0" minWidth="0" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100"/>
        </content>
    </Tab>

2- Setting the style in the Controller
// an attribute of my Controller class
@FXML public Tab tabRed;

// inside the constructor of said Controller
tabRed.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red;");

Note that I must use these versions of Java/JavaFX for reasons I do not control.

The default style rule for tab headers is in modena.css.  Override it in your own stylesheet.  Don't use an inline setStyle call as setStyle is not capable of defining rules by selectors.  The substructure used for defining selectors is also documented in the css reference.

The way I found that works is the following:
In my .fxml
<Tab fx:id="tabRed" text="Tab 2" styleClass="red-tab">
    <content>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0" minWidth="0" prefHeight="100" prefWidth="100"/>
    </content>
</Tab>

In my .css
.red-tab .tab-label{
   -fx-text-fill: red;
}


You should update the title a little to clearly mention that the request is to set a single tab to red out of many. Please also accept your answer to show that this is the working approach.

Done @AKSingh, thanks! I can't accept my own answer just yet

Use a CSS file and link the file to your FXML layout. You can check this answer How to add a CSS stylesheet in FXML.
In the CSS, you can add the following to style the label colour:
.tab .tab-label {
-fx-text-fill: red;
}


This doesn't work for me. For context, I already have an external CSS file linked programmatically, like so:
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
Which is exactly the same as the second answer, and it works for the other things I'm styling. However, the text doesn't come out as red but as black still.

I also tried to link it like in the first answer, but again the text is not red. As for the css, I tried both .tab-name .tab-label and .tab .tab-name and it didn't work.

Oh okay, I tried your answer again and realized you're answering a different question. Like I said in the question, " I want to set the color of a single Tab to red.". You're setting the text of all tabs to red.
